# App crashing when displaying Google Maps

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, google-maps, uibutton

so I've been trying to add the Google Maps API/SDK to my iOS application. However, I am having an issue where the app always crashes when I click the button for the next view controller that contains Google Maps to appear.

Here is what my controllers look like:

[image]
[image]

It seems to be crashing at the AppDelgate. Here is what the output is:

> 2015-08-08 19:43:09.341 TestPlattrApp[7902:172964] Unable to
>   simultaneously satisfy constraints.   Probably at least one of the
>   constraints in the following list is one you don't want. Try this: (1)
>   look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect;
>   (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints
>   and fix it. (Note: If you're seeing
>   NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraints that you don't understand, refer
>   to the documentation for the UIView property
>   translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints)  (
>       "",
>       "",
>       "",
>       "",
>       "",
>       "",
>       "",
>       "",
>       "" )
>
> Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint
>
> Make a symbolic breakpoint at UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints
>   to catch this in the debugger. The methods in the
>   UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in
>    may also be helpful. 2015-08-08 19:43:12.295
>   TestPlattrApp[7902:172964] Unable to simultaneously satisfy
>   constraints.  Probably at least one of the constraints in the
>   following list is one you don't want. Try this: (1) look at each
>   constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; (2) find the
>   code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it.
>   (Note: If you're seeing NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraints that you
>   don't understand, refer to the documentation for the UIView property
>   translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints)  (
>       "",
>       "",
>       "",
>       "",
>       "",
>       "",
>       "" )
>
> Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint
>
> Make a symbolic breakpoint at UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints
>   to catch this in the debugger. The methods in the
>   UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in
>    may also be helpful. 2015-08-08 19:43:12.296
>   TestPlattrApp[7902:172964] Unable to simultaneously satisfy
>   constraints.  Probably at least one of the constraints in the
>   following list is one you don't want. Try this: (1) look at each
>   constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; (2) find the
>   code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it.
>   (Note: If you're seeing NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraints that you
>   don't understand, refer to the documentation for the UIView property
>   translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints)  (
>       "",
>       "",
>       "",
>       "",
>       "",
>       "",
>       "" )
>
> Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint
>
> Make a symbolic breakpoint at UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints
>   to catch this in the debugger. The methods in the
>   UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in
>    may also be helpful. 2015-08-08 19:43:12.297
>   TestPlattrApp[7902:172964] Unable to simultaneously satisfy
>   constraints.  Probably at least one of the constraints in the
>   following list is one you don't want. Try this: (1) look at each
>   constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; (2) find the
>   code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it.
>   (Note: If you're seeing NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraints that you
>   don't understand, refer to the documentation for the UIView property
>   translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints)  (
>       "",
>       "",
>       "
>   (Names: '|':UIView:0x7f9ad8ff5f00 )>",
>       "",
>       "" )
>
> Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint
>
> Make a symbolic breakpoint at UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints
>   to catch this in the debugger. The methods in the
>   UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in
>    may also be helpful. 2015-08-08 19:43:12.298
>   TestPlattrApp[7902:172964] Unable to simultaneously satisfy
>   constraints.  Probably at least one of the constraints in the
>   following list is one you don't want. Try this: (1) look at each
>   constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; (2) find the
>   code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it.
>   (Note: If you're seeing NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraints that you
>   don't understand, refer to the documentation for the UIView property
>   translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints)  (
>       "",
>       "",
>       "",
>       "",
>       "",
>       "",
>       "",
>       "<_UILayoutSupportConstraint:0x7f9ad8ff4a20 V:[_UILayoutGuide:0x7f9ad8ff9740(64)]>",
>       "<_UILayoutSupportConstraint:0x7f9ad8ff6d90 V:|-(0)-[_UILayoutGuide:0x7f9ad8ff9740]   (Names:
>   '|':UIView:0x7f9ad8ff5f00 )>",
>       "<_UILayoutSupportConstraint:0x7f9ad8ff4350 V:[_UILayoutGuide:0x7f9ad8ff9a70(0)]>",
>       "<_UILayoutSupportConstraint:0x7f9ad8ff4430 _UILayoutGuide:0x7f9ad8ff9a70.bottom == UIView:0x7f9ad8ff5f00.bottom>",
>       "" )
>
> Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint
>
> Make a symbolic breakpoint at UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints
>   to catch this in the debugger. The methods in the
>   UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in
>    may also be helpful. 2015-08-08 19:43:12.299
>   TestPlattrApp[7902:172964] Unable to simultaneously satisfy
>   constraints.  Probably at least one of the constraints in the
>   following list is one you don't want. Try this: (1) look at each
>   constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; (2) find the
>   code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it.
>   (Note: If you're seeing NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraints that you
>   don't understand, refer to the documentation for the UIView property
>   translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints)  (
>       "",
>       "",
>       "",
>       "",
>       "",
>       "",
>       "",
>       "",
>       "<_UILayoutSupportConstraint:0x7f9ad8ff4a20 V:[_UILayoutGuide:0x7f9ad8ff9740(64)]>",
>       "<_UILayoutSupportConstraint:0x7f9ad8ff6d90 V:|-(0)-[_UILayoutGuide:0x7f9ad8ff9740]   (Names:
>   '|':UIView:0x7f9ad8ff5f00 )>",
>       "<_UILayoutSupportConstraint:0x7f9ad8ff4350 V:[_UILayoutGuide:0x7f9ad8ff9a70(0)]>",
>       "<_UILayoutSupportConstraint:0x7f9ad8ff4430 _UILayoutGuide:0x7f9ad8ff9a70.bottom == UIView:0x7f9ad8ff5f00.bottom>",
>       "" )
>
> Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint
>
> Make a symbolic breakpoint at UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints
>   to catch this in the debugger. The methods in the
>   UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in
>    may also be helpful. 2015-08-08 19:43:12.301
>   TestPlattrApp[7902:172964] Unable to simultaneously satisfy
>   constraints.  Probably at least one of the constraints in the
>   following list is one you don't want. Try this: (1) look at each
>   constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; (2) find the
>   code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it.
>   (Note: If you're seeing NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraints that you
>   don't understand, refer to the documentation for the UIView property
>   translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints)  (
>       "",
>       "",
>       "",
>       "",
>       "",
>       "<_UILayoutSupportConstraint:0x7f9ad8ff4a20 V:[_UILayoutGuide:0x7f9ad8ff9740(64)]>",
>       "<_UILayoutSupportConstraint:0x7f9ad8ff6d90 V:|-(0)-[_UILayoutGuide:0x7f9ad8ff9740]   (Names:
>   '|':UIView:0x7f9ad8ff5f00 )>",
>       "<_UILayoutSupportConstraint:0x7f9ad8ff4350 V:[_UILayoutGuide:0x7f9ad8ff9a70(0)]>",
>       "<_UILayoutSupportConstraint:0x7f9ad8ff4430 _UILayoutGuide:0x7f9ad8ff9a70.bottom == UIView:0x7f9ad8ff5f00.bottom>",
>       "" )
>
> Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint
>
> Make a symbolic breakpoint at UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints
>   to catch this in the debugger. The methods in the
>   UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in
>    may also be helpful. 2015-08-08 19:43:12.302
>   TestPlattrApp[7902:172964] Unable to simultaneously satisfy
>   constraints.  Probably at least one of the constraints in the
>   following list is one you don't want. Try this: (1) look at each
>   constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; (2) find the
>   code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it.
>   (Note: If you're seeing NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraints that you
>   don't understand, refer to the documentation for the UIView property
>   translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints)  (
>       "",
>       "",
>       "",
>       "",
>       "",
>       "",
>       "",
>       "",
>       "",
>       "<_UILayoutSupportConstraint:0x7f9ad8ff4a20 V:[_UILayoutGuide:0x7f9ad8ff9740(64)]>",
>       "<_UILayoutSupportConstraint:0x7f9ad8ff6d90 V:|-(0)-[_UILayoutGuide:0x7f9ad8ff9740]   (Names:
>   '|':UIView:0x7f9ad8ff5f00 )>",
>       "<_UILayoutSupportConstraint:0x7f9ad8ff4350 V:[_UILayoutGuide:0x7f9ad8ff9a70(0)]>",
>       "<_UILayoutSupportConstraint:0x7f9ad8ff4430 _UILayoutGuide:0x7f9ad8ff9a70.bottom == UIView:0x7f9ad8ff5f00.bottom>",
>       "" )
>
> Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint
>
> Make a symbolic breakpoint at UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints
>   to catch this in the debugger. The methods in the
>   UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in
>    may also be helpful. 2015-08-08 19:43:12.303
>   TestPlattrApp[7902:172964] Unable to simultaneously satisfy
>   constraints.  Probably at least one of the constraints in the
>   following list is one you don't want. Try this: (1) look at each
>   constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; (2) find the
>   code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it.
>   (Note: If you're seeing NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraints that you
>   don't understand, refer to the documentation for the UIView property
>   translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints)  (
>       "",
>       "",
>       "",
>       "",
>       "",
>       "",
>       "",
>       "" )
>
> Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint
>
> Make a symbolic breakpoint at UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints
>   to catch this in the debugger. The methods in the
>   UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in
>    may also be helpful. 2015-08-08 19:43:12.304
>   TestPlattrApp[7902:172964] Unable to simultaneously satisfy
>   constraints.  Probably at least one of the constraints in the
>   following list is one you don't want. Try this: (1) look at each
>   constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; (2) find the
>   code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it.
>   (Note: If you're seeing NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraints that you
>   don't understand, refer to the documentation for the UIView property
>   translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints)  (
>       "",
>       "",
>       "",
>       "",
>       "<_UILayoutSupportConstraint:0x7f9ad8ff4a20 V:[_UILayoutGuide:0x7f9ad8ff9740(64)]>",
>       "<_UILayoutSupportConstraint:0x7f9ad8ff6d90 V:|-(0)-[_UILayoutGuide:0x7f9ad8ff9740]   (Names:
>   '|':UIView:0x7f9ad8ff5f00 )>",
>       "<_UILayoutSupportConstraint:0x7f9ad8ff4350 V:[_UILayoutGuide:0x7f9ad8ff9a70(0)]>",
>       "<_UILayoutSupportConstraint:0x7f9ad8ff4430 _UILayoutGuide:0x7f9ad8ff9a70.bottom == UIView:0x7f9ad8ff5f00.bottom>",
>       "",
>       ""
>   )
>
> Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint
>
> Make a symbolic breakpoint at UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints
>   to catch this in the debugger. The methods in the
>   UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in
>    may also be helpful. 2015-08-08 19:43:15.296
>   TestPlattrApp[7902:172964] -[TestPlattrApp.ResturantIdInputScreen
>   searchForNearByResturants:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance
>   0x7f9ad8ff1e70 2015-08-08 19:43:15.307 TestPlattrApp[7902:172964] ***
>   Terminating app due to uncaught exception
>   'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason:
>   '-[TestPlattrApp.ResturantIdInputScreen searchForNearByResturants:]:
>   unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7f9ad8ff1e70'
>   *** First throw call stack: (     0   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000111bf4c65 **exceptionPreprocess + 165  1   libobjc.A.dylib
>
>   0x000000011379abb7 objc_exception_throw + 45  2   CoreFoundation
>
>   0x0000000111bfc0ad -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] +
>   205   3   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000111b5213c
>   ___forwarding_** + 988    4   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000111b51cd8 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 120  5   UIKit
>   0x0000000112494d62 -[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] + 75
>     6   UIKit                               0x00000001125a650a
>   -[UIControl _sendActionsForEvents:withEvent:] + 467   7   UIKit                               0x00000001125a58d9 -[UIControl touchesEnded:withEvent:] + 522   8
>   UIKit                               0x00000001124e1958 -[UIWindow
>   _sendTouchesForEvent:] + 735  9   UIKit                               0x00000001124e2282 -[UIWindow sendEvent:] + 682     10  UIKit
>   0x00000001124a8541 -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 246  11  UIKit
>   0x00000001124b5cdc _UIApplicationHandleEventFromQueueEvent + 18265    12
>   UIKit                               0x000000011249059c
>   _UIApplicationHandleEventQueue + 2066     13  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000111b28431
>   **CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION** + 17   14  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000111b1e2fd
>   __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 269   15  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000111b1d934 __CFRunLoopRun + 868     16  CoreFoundation
>   0x0000000111b1d366 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 470     17  GraphicsServices
>   0x0000000115176a3e GSEventRunModal + 161  18  UIKit
>   0x00000001124938c0 UIApplicationMain + 1282   19  TestPlattrApp
>   0x000000010f5f7407 main + 135     20  libdyld.dylib
>   0x0000000113ed0145 start + 1 ) libc++abi.dylib: terminating with
>   uncaught exception of type NSException (lldb)

Comment: You've got a bunch of interface builder issues which are generating many of your errors. `[TestPlattrApp.ResturantIdInputScreen searchForNearByResturants:]` is where your problem lives.

Comment: Yeah you're right, I had messed up my stuff there. Thanks for the help bud!

Comment: The custom is to upvote :)

Comment: I just googled it, I dont have enough rep to upvote/down vote comments yet :(